# list view display only few elements

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

I have 800 titles for implements the list view. I put those 800 titles in a string-array and then I try to populate the list view, but when I try to run  I can only display at least 10 elements. When I try to search a title with the search bar I can found it and then when I delete the filter search I can see the total array of title. What I'm wrong??
Here is the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_titoli);

        btt_backHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btt_backHome);
        lV_titoli = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lV_titoli);
        eT_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eT_search);

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.titoli, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        adapter_testi = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.testi, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        lV_titoli.setAdapter(adapter);

        final Intent refresh = new Intent(this, activity_titoli.class);
        final Intent to_Home = new Intent (this , Activity_Main.class);
        final Intent to_Canzone_from_titoli = new Intent (this , activity_canzone.class);

        eT_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                (activity_titoli.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
            }
        });
```

I've already verify that the string-array named "titoli" is the correct one.

Comment: comment the line initialising `adapter_testi` and see if this happens then too.

Comment: no It doesn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

It is a peculiar behavior but since filter resolves it, try:

```
adapter.getFilter().filter("");
```

right after

```
lV_titoli.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: no it doesn't work on my Huawei p10 lite, otherwise if I try to use an emulator it works correctly!! I've already installed the app on my physical phone and reinstalled but nothing worked..

Comment: So this is a one device issue?

Comment: I need to try whit another physical phone

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just a slow response from your device? Just wait few secs and then scroll down.